# Decision tree continuous attributes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I am making datamining model by using decision tree. And if I have binary attribute like MALE and FEMALE I know I will have two branches from the Gender node when splitting. But what if I have continuous attribute which is float number from 0 to 1. Do I map it to discrete values like LOW (0 - 0.5) and HIGH (0.5 - 1)? Or is there some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to split it by your own? I'm not sure I understood correctly.
However, the purpose of the decision trees is exactly what you seem to do by hand.

For a given feature **F** (Let's take the case of a continuous attribute), where values are within **(a, b)** (it can be **]-∞, +∞[** ), the decision tree looks for the *best** value **V** to split your node into two separate leaves. Thus data belong to the first leaf if the attribute **F** is within **(a, V)**, and to the second leaf if within **(V, b)**

**What** *best** **means**?

They are multiple ways to find the value **V** but generally speaking, it is such that the *purity* (literature term) of each leaf is maximal, meaning that the data inside are somehow homogeneous. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Metrics) gives some commonly used metrics to split each parent leaf within two child leaves.

Comment: I know that Information gain (Entropy reduction) is the metrics when choosing by which of attributes to do splitting, but I was unsure when choosing cut point for single attribute. I understand what you are saying but how should algorithm know which are best candidates for cut point when interval is continous, I must choose some values and then see what metrics is with that values. For instance 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0 .8, right?

Comment: Alogrithm itself must somehow be "told" by user which candidate cut points to look for...

Comment: No, that the point. He'll take the _best_ cut point according to a minimization function. You should check, for instance, sklearn implementation of the decision trees : they do not require any candidate cut points as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, you don't need to worry about finding the best attribute. But if you have loads of floats as attributes computation time for each value is expensive. In that case have a look at discretization algorithms in decision trees.

So in your example when applying binary discretization techniques, your continuous attribute will be transformed into a discrete binary attribute. There are loads of discretizaion techniques, that use different approaches to find the perfect threshold between the classes (in your case 0.5).